# How to fix the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nunique'?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently receiving the error below when trying to run my code at the end. I thought that my pandas might be out of date, but I've already upgraded it to the latest version so I'm unsure what could be the issue.

```
n_ratings = len(ratings)
n_members = ratings['anime_id'].nuninque()
n_anime = ratings['user_id'].nuninque()
n_genre = ratings['genre'].nuninque()
```

The error message below when I run the program

```
----> 2 n_members = ratings_df["anime_id"].nuninque()
      3 n_anime = ratings_df["user_id"].nuninque()
      4 n_genre = ratings_df["genre"].nuninque()
```

```
-> 5575         DataFrame.head : The first `n` rows of the caller object.
   5576 
   5577         Examples

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'nuninque'
```

Comment: Typo. `nuninque` != `nunique`

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I can't believe I didn't notice that...thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointed out by Alexander L.Hayes. The issue with the error above is that there was a type `Nuninque` != `nunique`